# Using logical operations inside a for loop header

Tags: for-loop, initialization, logical-operators

sIn the following code:

```
 for( ( i = j = 0 ); ( i < 3 ) && ( j < 3 ); ( i ++ ) & ( j ++ ) )
 {
    /* Some code */
 }
```

OR

```
for( ( i = 0 ) & ( j = 0 ); ( i < 3 ) && ( j < 3 ); ( i ++ ) & ( j ++ ) )
 {
    /* Some code */
 }
```

When running the code, a warning message appears saying: value computed is not used. Why is that ? Providing that the code isn't functioning well due to the logical errors!
Please help ..

Answer (score 1):

Is this something that you want :

```
for(  i = 0,j = 0 ;  i < 3 && j<3;  i++ , j++ )
{
/* your code */
}
```

This should work fine in case you want to use two variables in one for loop.
This way both i and j will be initialized to 0 and both with get incremented by 1 and the less than condition will check for the limit for both variables

In case, you want to loop through two arrays you can do something like this :

```
int[] arr1 = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
int[] arr2= new int[]{6,7,8,9,0,11};
for( i = 0,j = 0 ;  i< arr1.length && j<arr2.length;  i++ , j++ )
  {
     System.out.println(arr1[i] + " " +arr2[j]);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you Ms. @Sana for your help. I want to add that the code should be looping or scanning two arrays simultaneously. For that I wanted a loop mechanism to do such work.